# How to draw a feynman triangle loop using feynMF package?

Tags: overleaf, feynman, feynmf

I am trying to produce this diagram:

[image]

So far my code looks the following:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\unitlength=1mm

\begin{document}



\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\captionsetup{format = hang} % align the text in the caption to the left of figure
\begin{fmffile}{diagram}
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(60,45)
    % External vertices on the left
    \fmfleft{i1}
    % External vertices on the right
    \fmfright{o1,o2}
    % Labels on external vertices
    \fmflabel{$C(p-k)$}{o1}
    \fmflabel{$A(P)$}{i1}
    \fmflabel{$A(k)$}{o2}
    \fmf{plain}{i1,b1}
    \fmf{plain}{b3,o2}
    \fmf{plain}{b2,o1}
    \fmf{plain_arrow,tension=.10}{b1,b3}
    \fmf{plain_arrow,tension=.10}{b1,b2}
    \fmf{plain_arrow,tension=.10}{b3,b2}
    %\fmfv{decor.shape=triangle,decor.filled=empty,decor.size=.30w}{b}
   % \fmfblob{.19w}{b}
   % \fmffreeze
    \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
    
    \vspace*{3mm}
    \caption{ Decay of a particle with mass $P^2 = m_i^2$ into two with masses $p_1^2 = p_2^2 = m_{\pi}^2$ and one with mass $p_3^2 = m_f^2$}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which gives me

[image]

how can I have horizontal external lines on the Right side?

Comment: Welcome. // Please make it your habit to post code, which starts with \documentclass and ends with \end{document}. Makes things easeir for all of us. // I suggest to add a screenshot of what your current code draws, and indicate, what's missing.

Comment: Sorry, even with good will your code fragment does not compile for me. Please make it compile for all of us. // You may also have a look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feynmf or here https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=feynmf , i.e. search on this site.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice, I edited the code such that it can be compiled

Comment: The sample code still didn't compile correctly due to a missing \usepackage{caption} so I have edited it to fix it.

Comment: I edited it, does it compile correctly now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With quite a lot of more advanced diagrams or where more control is needed the `\ffmffreeze` command is very useful. This command allows feynmf to calculate positions with the information given so far and then lock all vertexes in place, but allows further lines to be added in later.

This is especially powerful when used with lines of type phantom which contribute to the layout rules but don't render at all.

Using these techniques we can produce the graph requested using the following code

```
    \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\usepackage{caption}
\unitlength=1mm

\begin{document}



\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\captionsetup{format = hang} % align the text in the caption to the left of figure
\begin{fmffile}{diagram}
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(60,45)
    % External vertices on the left
    \fmfleft{i1,i2,i3}
    % External vertices on the right
    \fmfright{o1,o2,o3}
    % Labels on external vertices
    \fmflabel{$A(P)$}{i2}
    \fmflabel{$C(p-k)$}{o1}
    \fmflabel{$A(k)$}{o3}
    \fmf{plain}{b1,o1}
    \fmf{plain}{i2,b2}
    \fmf{plain}{b3,o3}
    \fmf{phantom,tension=0.35}{b1,i1}
    \fmf{phantom,tension=0.35}{b2,o2}
    \fmf{phantom,tension=0.35}{b3,i3}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmf{plain_arrow}{b1,b3}
    \fmf{plain_arrow}{b1,b2}
    \fmf{plain_arrow}{b3,b2}
    %\fmfv{decor.shape=triangle,decor.filled=empty,decor.size=.30w}{b}
   % \fmfblob{.19w}{b}
   % \fmffreeze
    \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
    
    \vspace*{3mm}
    \caption{ Decay of a particle with mass $P^2 = m_i^2$ into two with masses $p_1^2 = p_2^2 = m_{\pi}^2$ and one with mass $p_3^2 = m_f^2$}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which gives the graph
[image: Feynman Graph]

With a little further use of phantom lines and tension we can produce a digram that is very close to the sample given above (with the triangle rotated but the legs still horiontal) using the code

```
    \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\usepackage{caption}
\unitlength=1mm

\begin{document}



\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\captionsetup{format = hang} % align the text in the caption to the left of figure
\begin{fmffile}{diagram}
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(100,45)
    % External vertices on the left
    \fmfstraight
    \fmfleft{_,i1,_,i2,_,i3,_}
    % External vertices on the right
    \fmfright{_,o1,_,o2,_,o3a,_}
    \fmftop{_,_,t1,_,t2,_,_}
    \fmfbottom{_,_,b1,_,b2,_,_}
    % Labels on external vertices
    \fmflabel{$A(P)$}{i2}
    \fmflabel{$C(p-k)$}{o1}
    \fmflabel{$A(k)$}{o3}
    \fmf{plain}{x1,o1}
    \fmf{plain}{i2,x2}
    \fmf{plain}{x3,o3}
    \fmf{phantom,tension=2}{o3,o3a}
    \fmf{phantom,tension=0.3}{x1,i1}
    \fmf{phantom,tension=0.3}{x2,o2}
    \fmf{phantom,tension=0.4}{x3,i3}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmf{plain_arrow}{x1,x3}
    \fmf{plain_arrow}{x1,x2}
    \fmf{plain_arrow}{x3,x2}
    \fmf{dashes}{t1,b1}
    \fmf{dashes}{t2,b2}
    %\fmfv{decor.shape=triangle,decor.filled=empty,decor.size=.30w}{b}
   % \fmfblob{.19w}{b}
   % \fmffreeze
    \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
    
    \vspace*{3mm}
    \caption{ Decay of a particle with mass $P^2 = m_i^2$ into two with masses $p_1^2 = p_2^2 = m_{\pi}^2$ and one with mass $p_3^2 = m_f^2$}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which produces the diagram
[image: Skew Triangle Feynman Diagram]

Note that the tensions have been chosen so that the top leg is the same length as the bottom leg but is half a leg length further across.

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful.

Comment: I am still wondering why you are not just using \fmfleft{i1,i2,i3} for defining the external lines. In the second code, you have used an underscore in between

Comment: In the second example you mean? The first entry in the left points is at the very top left corner of the diagram. I wanted the two vertical lines to go higher (and lower) than the external horizontal legs so needed to not use the very first entry in left. The same logic applies for not using the last entry and for the right side. The extra entries in the middle then spread out the entries so they don't bunch up too much in the centre and just leave some space at the top and bottom.